# how to use beast::http::async_read

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm trying to write a simple http server. while `beast::http::read` is working as respected, The async version does not call the handler at all (when trying to get `http://localhost:8080/`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
using tcp = asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    asio::io_context m_io_context;
    tcp::acceptor m_acceptor(m_io_context, {tcp::v4(), 8080});
    tcp::socket m_socket(m_io_context);
    beast::flat_buffer buffer;
    beast::http::request<beast::http::string_body> request;

    m_acceptor.accept(m_socket);

    while (true)
    {
        // Do something...
        //beast::http::read(m_socket, buffer, request);  // This works well
        beast::http::async_read(
            m_socket, buffer, request,
            [](const beast::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
            {
                // This function is never being called!!
                // ...
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add more details as to what you mean by `// Do something...`, it will increase your chances of getting helped.

Comment: `// This function is never being called!!` That's because you never call any of `post[_one]` or `run[_one]` functions required for async handlers to work.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on boost documentation on [async_read](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__http__async_read/overload1.html), t*he function call always returns immediately.* So your callback won't be processed, to make it work, you need to execute [run](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context/run/overload1.html) of the *m_io_context* object. Take a look on boost [documentation example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/http/server/async/http_server_async.cpp).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
using tcp = asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    asio::io_context m_io_context;
    tcp::acceptor m_acceptor(m_io_context, {tcp::v4(), 8080});
    tcp::socket m_socket(m_io_context);
    beast::flat_buffer buffer;
    beast::http::request<beast::http::string_body> request;

    m_acceptor.accept(m_socket);

    beast::http::async_read(
        m_socket, buffer, request,
        [](const beast::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
        {
            // start the next async read here
        });

    m_io_context.run();
}
```

Comment: But `m_io_context.run();` is blocking. I want my thread to do other things while waiting for requests.

Comment: then you can run a context in the different thread and check the example, this is exactly what you are asking

Comment: This makes no sense. If I wanted to use another thread - I could simply use `beast::http::read`. what is the logic of having an async version of read, when you must block your thread?

Comment: @DuduArbel use a timer "to do other things"

Comment: @DuduArbel what are the `other things` ? there is a `poll` method you can use instead of `run` to "poll" the eventloop instead of running it to completion, but using it to mix two eventloops together is pretty complex.

Comment: @DuduArbel the beast doesn't create any thread inside for async processing, you need to handle it in your code.

Comment: @DuduArbel Go here for the starter: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html, and yes you are free to do everything on a single thread. It just means you have to multiplex all the IO on the same thread